# using ng-include for a template that has directives that use data retrieved by XHR

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I am using ng-include in order to include a persistent menu, that exists in all of the views of my SPA.

The problem is that I want to display different options and content in this menu per each user type(admin, guest, user etc.), and this requires the service function authService.loadCurrentUser to be resolved first.

For the purpose of managing this content easily and comfortably, I have created a simple directive, that takes an attribute with the required access level, and at the compile phase
of the element, if the permissions of the given user are not sufficient, removes the element and it's children.

So after failing miserably at trying to make the ng-include go through the routeProvider function, I've tried to use ng-init, but nothing seems to work, the user role remain undefined at the time that I am logging it out.

I am thinking about trying a new approach, and making the entire menu a directive that includes the template that is suitable for each user type, but first I would like to try and solve this matter.

Directive:

```
'use strict';
/* Directives */
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).
directive('restrict', function(authService){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        prioriry: 100000,
        scope: {
            // : '@'
        },
        link: function(){
            // alert('ergo sum!');
        },
        compile:  function(element, attr, linker){
            var user = authService.getUser();
                if(user.role != attr.access){
                console.log(attr.access);
                console.log(user.role);//Always returns undefined!
                    element.children().remove();
                    element.remove();           
                }

        }
    }
});
```

Service:

```
'use strict';
/* Services */
angular.module('myApp.services', []).
factory('authService', function ($http, $q) {
    var authServ = {};
    var that = this;
    that.currentUser = {};
    authServ.authUser = function () {
        return $http.head('/users/me', {
            withCredentials: true
        });
    },
    authServ.getUser = function () {
        return that.currentUser;
    },
    authServ.setCompany = function (companyId) {
        that.currentUser.company = companyId;
    },
    authServ.loadCurrentUser = function () {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/users/me', {
            withCredentials: true
        }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
            that.currentUser.company = {};
            that.currentUser.company.id = that.currentUser.company.id ? that.currentUser.company.id : data.main_company;            
            that.currentUser.companies = [];
            for (var i in data.roles) {
                that.currentUser.companies[data.roles[i]['company']] = data.roles[i]['company_name'];
                if (data.roles[i]['company'] == that.currentUser.company.id){
                    that.currentUser.role = data.roles[i]['role_type']; 
                    that.currentUser.company.name = data.roles[i]['company_name'];
                    // console.log(that.currentUser.role);
                } 
            }
            // defer.resolve(data);
            defer.resolve();
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            that.currentUser.role = 'guest';
            that.currentUser.company = 1;
            defer.reject("reject");
        });  
    return defer.promise;
    }

    return authServ;
});
```

Menu controller:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
controller('menuCtrl', function($scope, $route, $location, authService){
    //TODO: Check if this assignment should be local to each $scope func in order to be compliant with 2-way data binding
    $scope.user = authService.getUser();
    console.log($scope.user);
    // $scope.companies = $scope.user.companies;
    $scope.companyOpts = function(){
        // var user = authService.getUser();
        if(typeof $scope.user.company == 'undefined')
            return;

            var companies = [];
            companies[$scope.user.company.id] = $scope.user.company.name;
            for(var i in $scope.user.companies){
                if(i != $scope.user.company.id){
                    companies[i] = $scope.user.companies[i];    
                }
            }
            // console.log(companies);
            // if(nonCurrentComapnies.length > 0){
                console.log(companies);
                return companies;
            // }
    }



    $scope.$watch('user.company.name', function(company){
        for(var i in $scope.user.companies)
            if(company == $scope.user.companies[i].id)
                authService.setCompany(i);
    });
    $scope.$watch(function(){return authService.getUser().company; }, function(company){
        //Refresh the page on company change here, first time, and each time the user changes the select
        // $scope.companyOpts();
        // $scope.currentComapany = company;
    })
;})
```

Main SPA HTML page:

```
<div ng-init="authservice.loadCurrentUser" ng-include src="'partials/menu.html'"></div>
```

menu element that should be visible only to the admin:

```
<ul class="left" restrict access="admin">
  <li>You are the admin!</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Post your controller code.

Comment: posted, I am not sure that it's relevant though

Comment: Relevant for sure, you're using `ng-init="authservice.loadCurrentUser"`, so `authservice` must be attached to `$scope`, appears you don't have it, then `authservice.loadCurrentUser` won't be called. Plus, you should use `ng-init="authservice.loadCurrentUser()"` to actually call the function.

Comment: I tried it both ways, and eventually decided that it's kind of an angular convention to strip the braces from the function in the HTML syntax.

Anyways, how to I attach the scope to authService?

Comment: Where did you see `it's kind of an angular convention to strip the braces from the function in the HTML syntax`? I'm interested to know. `ngInit` takes an expression, `authservice.loadCurrentUser` will be evaluated to a function, `authservice.loadCurrentUser()` will be evaluated as a function call. For the scope, you just need `$sopce.authService = authService`.

Comment: @YeLiu : did as you instructed me, still getting undefined logged out :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35492/discussion-between-oleg-tikhonov-and-ye-liu)

Answer (score 1):

I personally would do the "reverse" way. Which mean: I will add the menu in when the user role is "admin", or "user", etc...

This way, you can do something like this in the "restrict" directive:

```
    ...
    var roleListener = $scope.$watch('user.role', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal == $scope.access) {
            // add the menu items
            // supposed that loadcurrentuser be called only once
            // we should clear the watch
            roleListener();
        } else {
            // personally, I would remove the item here too
            // so the menu would be added or removed when user.role update
        }
    });
    ...
```

One more thing, for just display menu base on the user role, you can use [ngSwitch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch), something like this:

```
    <ul class="left" ng-switch="user.role">
        <li ng-switch-when="admin">You are the admin!</li>
        <li ng-switch-when="user">You are the user!</li>
        <li ng-switch-default><img src="some-thing-running.gif"/>Your menu is loading, please wait...</li>
    </ul>
```

And let the magical AngularJS binding render up the menus for you!

Answer (score 0):

The call to authServ.getUser  should also return a promise by calling internally

```
authServ.loadCurrentUser
```

which should be modified a bit to check if the user context exists to avoid making another API call and always returning resolve with the user context:

```
defer.resolve(that.currentUser);
```

Loading the user context should also be done early on as this enables the authorization of the app. The app.run function can be used for this purpose.

hope it helps others.